# How to Create a Brush in Swift with Force Touch Sensitivity?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to implement a brush in Swift that changes its thickness and alpha based on Force Touch sensitivity. I want the thickness and alpha changing smoothly and gradually at the start and end. How can I achieve this?

Details:
I'm working on a drawing app where users can use Force Touch to control the thickness and opacity of the brush. I've managed to get the Force Touch value using force property of UITouch, but I'm not sure how to use this value to smoothly change the brush thickness and alpha.
[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
    class DrawingView: UIView {
    var path = UIBezierPath()
    var startPoint = CGPoint()
    var touchPoint = CGPoint()
    var shape =  UIImage(named:"square-outline")

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let point = touch?.location(in: self) {
            startPoint = point
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let point = touch?.location(in: self) {
            touchPoint = point
        }
      let scale = touch.force

        let imageLayer = CALayer()
        imageLayer.transform = CATransform3DScale(imageLayer.transform, scale, scale, 1)
        imageLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        imageLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y , width: 20, height: 20)
        imageLayer.position = CGPoint(x:touchPoint.x ,y:touchPoint.y)
        imageLayer.contents = shape?.cgImage
        self.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
        
        
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
    }
}

extension CALayer {
    func rotate(angle: CGFloat) {
        let a = CGFloat(angle * .pi/180)
        let trans  =  CATransform3DMakeRotation(a, 0, 0, 1)
     self.transform = trans
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to achieve this effect. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're setting the layer's `transform` based on the touch force ... have you tried also setting the layer's `.opacity`?

Comment: yes,  
                let minopacity:CGFloat = CGFloat(1.0-dynamicOpacity)
                let dunamicOpacity:CGFloat = minopacity+(CGFloat(idx)/300.0) <= brushAlpha ? minopacity+(CGFloat(idx)/300.0) : brushAlpha
                
                
                
                imageLayer.opacity = Float(dunamicOpacity)

Comment: `layer.opacity` should be a value between `0.0` and `1.0`